# How to indent/shift a line of code or a block of code in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea, shift

I can shift a line of code or a block of code in Eclipse by the following way:

1. Focus a line or select a block of source code
2. Source menu -> Click "Shift Left" or "Shift Right"

How to do the same thing in IntelliJ IDEA?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Assuming we use "shift" and "indent" as synonyms:

- [Tab] (to move things further to the right)
- [Shift] + [Tab] (to move things further left)

It will do (almost) the same in Eclipse and IntelliJ.

For the commands above we assume that *you selected at least one character*, if you just place your cursor somewhere the [tab] key will obviously just insert a tab (or some spaces, depending on your config).

Comment: +1, although I don't understand why someone might want to do this when Ctrl+Shift+F is available or formatting can be done automatically on save.

Comment: FYI - by default, `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`L` is to reformat ('L' for Layout). `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`F` is "Find in Path"

Comment: Yes, Tab and Tab+Shift is working for me. Thanks reto

Comment: Not sure why this option missing in context menu or Code Menu. many things in IDEA has bad UX compared to Eclipse

Comment: @reto: Yes "shift" and "indent" is synonym.

Comment: When Im using PyCharm or CLion, the tab does nothing, its very frustrating, how do u solve this? I want to be able to tab however I like. For example I put a comment above a function, lets say I want to for some reason want to tab it in two tabs, using eclipse, no problem. However jetbrains products does not let me do this, or is there some secret way to solve it?

Comment: Why was this so hard to find! I always need to un-indent code